# You don't have permission to access /oauth/token on this server

Tags: apache, tomcat, httpd.conf

I have Apche Server(httpd) on Front and tomcat.
I configed httpd.conf for redirect apache(port 80) to tomcat(port 8586).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html

  ProxyPass /error/ !
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8586/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8586/

  ErrorDocument 503 /error/updating.html
</VirtualHost>
```

in http://pstar.ir domain Everything works fine.
but in http://panel.pstar.ir when login page
first time login action work correctly.
but Later times not work and throw exception in following.

```
You don't have permission to access /oauth/token on this server
```

if clear cache in chrome work correctly.
with first time request header contain X-XSRF-TOKEN
but later times,request header not contain X-XSRF-TOKEN
how to resolve this problem ?